# Order of update / checkout in svn

Tags: svn

Maybe my google skills just aren't what they should be, but I cannot figure this out: Why does svn update files in the order that it does?  This order has nothing to do with the order of a directory listing, and doesn't seem to correlate with the mtime of the files in the repository itself (the central repository, or my local repository).

One reason I'm curious is because that's the only way I could think of to see the progress of an update -- to see how many files svn had gotten through.  But it's impossible to tell when they're all out of order.  (Unfortunately, we have huge files, and I have slow internet.)

Answer (score 1):

You can predict that via

```
svn st -u
```

on command line or "check for modification" in TortoiseSVN (with button "check repository")

Comment: Okay, but why?  That doesn't correspond to the mtime on the files in the central repository.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a specific order there on that you could rely: it's simple up to the svn implementation in which order it takes the files, it can depend on its internal database or whatever else.